# How to draw vertical arrows toward a line between two coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

In this shape I need to draw the two vertical arrows from nodes toward the line as shown in red.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dtklogos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows, arrows}
\usepackage[hidelinks,pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}



% Information boxes
\newcommand*{\info}[4][16.3]{%
\node [ annotation, #3, scale=0.65, text width = #1em,
      inner sep = 2mm ] at (#2) {%
 \list{$\bullet$}{\topsep=0pt\itemsep=0pt\parsep=0pt
\parskip=0pt\labelwidth=8pt\leftmargin=8pt
\itemindent=0pt\labelsep=2pt}%
#4
\endlist
};
}
\begin{document}
 \vspace{3cm} 
  \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance = 1.3cm, thick,
 every node/.style = {rectangle, minimum width= 100mm, rounded corners=20pt, font = \Large\sffamily, black,
top color = green!40!white, bottom color = green!20!white,drop shadow, minimum height = 2.5cm}]
 \node[minimum height=3.2cm] (SWGDAM){\Large\sffamily\bfseries{Systems}};
 %\node[label={[top color=white, bottom color=white, circle, yshift=2cm, text width=2cm, minimum height=0cm] right:{\bf\Large\sffamily22}}] (SWGDAM) %%%%%%{\textbf{SWGDAM}\\Probabilistic Genotyping};
\coordinate [below = 3.5cm of SWGDAM, xshift=26cm] (Mitte);
\coordinate [below = 5.8cm of SWGDAM, xshift=26cm] (Unten);

\node (417) [below = of SWGDAM, xshift=-17cm, yshift=-1cm]     {11};
\node (4171) [right = of 417, top color=yellow, bottom color=yellow]     {12};
\node(4172) [right = of 4171, top color=yellow, bottom color=yellow]     {13};
\node(4173) [right = of 4172, top color=yellow, bottom color=yellow]     {14};

\centering


%\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, scale=1.0, xshift=6cm, every annotation/.style = {draw,
                 %fill = white, font = \Large}]

    \begin{scope}[ yshift=-22cm, xshift=0cm, every annotation/.style = {draw,
                 fill = white, font = \Large}]                              
\path[mindmap, scale=1.1, grow cyclic, concept color=black!90, text=white,
every node/.style={concept, circular drop shadow},
root/.style    = {concept,
  font=\large\bfseries\fontsize{28pt}{36pt}\selectfont, text width=10em},
level 1 concept/.append style={font=\Large\bfseries,
  sibling angle=180,  level 2/.append style={sibling angle=37.5}, text width=9.1em,
level distance=15em,inner sep=0pt},
level 2 concept/.append style={font=\bfseries\fontsize{28pt}{36pt}     
  \selectfont, level distance=15em, text width=9em},
]
  node[root] {450} [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=red!60!black] {
  node[concept](PCRparameters) {Parameters}
  %node[concept] {Ampers}
       [clockwise from=325]
      child { node[concept] (hold)
       {hold}}
   child { node[concept] (saturn)
       {Saturn}}
  child { node[concept] (variances)
    {Varied}} 
  child { node[concept] (lsae)
    {LSAE}}
  }
child[concept color=purple!90!black] {
  node {Simulations} [counterclockwise from=35]
    child { node (degradation) {Deg}} 
    child { node (inhibition) {\href{http://golatex.de/wiki/Hauptseite}{Inhibit}} }
    child { node (drops) {Drops}} 
    child { node (pulls) {\href{http://golatex.de/wiki/Hauptseite}{Pulls}} }
  };

 \coordinate [below =2cm of 4173] (4173c);
 \coordinate [below =2cm of 417] (417c);
 \coordinate [below =2cm of 4172] (4172c);
 \coordinate [below =2cm of 4171] (4171c);
 \end{scope}

   \draw[line width=0.1cm, black]
  (417c)    -- (4173c)
(417c)    -- (417)
(4171c)    -- (4171)
(4172c)    -- (4172)
(4173c)    -- (4173)
; 
\draw[-{>[scale=2.5,
      length=8,
      width=8]},bend right=45, line width=0.1cm, black] (degradation.north) .. controls ([xshift=0cm, yshift=2cm] degradation.north) and ([xshift=-1cm, yshift=-5cm] 4172c.south) .. (4172c.south);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the "intersection syntax" to specify coordinates: `(A|-B)` means the coordinate at the vertical of `A` and horizontal of `B`.

So, in your case:

```
\draw[-{>[scale=2.5, length=8, width=8]}, line width=0.1cm] 
     (drops) -- (drops|-4172c.south);

\draw[-{>[scale=2.5,length=8,width=8]}, line width=0.1cm] 
     (inhibition) -- (inhibition|-4172c.south);
```

Resulting in:

[image: Result]